# Can a flutter app conflict with other app?

Tags: flutter

Recently, a user told me that updating my flutter app made Spotify non-functional. Is it even possible? I haven't linked my app with Spotify.

Comment: No, any third-party application cannot interfere with other applications' operations, until and unless you've special privileges, like permission to draw over other apps. But simply the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put aside the general philosophical question of "How can I prove that something is not happening" as well as the possibility of security vulnerabilities, the only reasonable answer is: No, this cannot happen.

Apps are sandboxed, meaning they can only access what is contained inside their application. For everything else, they need to ask for explicit user permission. So an app cannot just "make another app stop working".